# Reduce install time to physical Android Wear device

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I'm attempting to develop an Android wear app, but it's becoming quite the headache. The build times aren't a problem, it is the rate at which the apk is uploaded and installed to the device. Each can take upwards of a couple minutes and the APK is <2MB. I am debugging over Bluetooth but I know that BT is capable of much faster upload speeds. The install speeds are just ridiculous and I don't know how I could speed them up.

Anyone had luck in hastening the upload and install times when debugging their Android Wear app?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple factors impact the installation time.

- Run method (if you push your debug version directly to your watch, it's much faster than relying on Android Wear app to synchronize)
- Size of your APK (of course)
- Watch system version: it seems that the 5.x version is using ART and installation time is increased
- The way to connect to your watch: debugging over Bluetooth is (very) much longer than using a USB cable

Comment: Ahh. Well with a Moto 360 I have no choice but to use bluetooth :(

And I am pushing my debug app directly to the wear device. But with a apk size of 1.94MB I don't see why uploading and installing would take a combined 5 minutes, especially when only minor changes were made from the previous build.

Comment: If you use Android Studio, you can take a look at the "Run" view. It will give you a clue on what takes time. About the "minor" changes part, whatever the changes you've done, the whole apk is compiled and it may take less time, but after that, it is fully sent and installed to your device. There is no incremental installation an Android.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use emulator (or Android Wear by USB connection) for most builds, and only for some important ones use a real device via Bluetooth.

This doesn't solve the problem but allows you to avoid it.

Comment: I might end up having to do this. I spent an hour just trying to fix a minor bug with over half of that time just waiting for it to upload and install.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator is the only way to go if you are using a watch that can only use Bluetooth to transfer data. The blue tooth interface that watches use is very limited - try syncing music to it and you will see what I mean :-)